# How to recover a .tar backup

Tags: linux, tar

I've a `.tar` backup, when I try to extract using below command.

```
tar -xvf backup.tar
```

Nothing is extracting and no errors or warning

Seems like its corrupted. Is there any way to recover the `.tar` backup?

Comment: Does `tar -tvf backup.tar` show anything?  It should list the contents of the tar file.

Comment: Run `tar -xvf backup.tar ; echo $?` and tell us the exit status. Is it 0?

Comment: tar -tvf backup.tar, shows nothing,

Comment: it's a common error to run `tar -cvf filename.tar` instead of `tar -xvf ...` (possibly because x is adjacent to c on the qwerty keyboard).  if you've accidentally done that, then backup.tar is wiped, beyond recovery unless you have another copy of it somewhere.

Comment: tar -xvf backup.tar; echo$? shows output 0

Comment: What's the actual size of backup.tar? Does the size make sense to you?

Comment: yes, 300MB and another backup file 607MB

Comment: Try cpio, see my answer below.

Comment: What's the output of `file backup.tar`?

Answer (score 1):

If `tar` fails to work due to a corrupted file, sometimes `cpio` is your friend:

```
cpio -ivd -H tar < backup.tar
```

`cpio` has been known to skip corrupted parts in a tar file. In this case you'll see a message about "skipping N bytes of junk".

Comment: Tried running cpio,
 cpio -ivd -H tar < backup.tar

1 block

this is the output, I'm seing

Comment: What does `file backup.tar` say? Is the archive even recognized as a tar one by `file`? Maybe it's compressed?

Comment: This is a backup file created by VestaCP control panel.

Comment: @Augustin (A)  so what does `file backup.tar` say? (B) Maybe a command like `v-restore-user` would help (see https://vestacp.com/docs/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try solution from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96431/582295 i.e. `-i`. I had 209G archive that extracted only to 90G files with `xf`, but using `xfi` i was able to extract additional files (with some error at the end, but still better than nothing).